# Citation within a Latex figure caption in rmarkdown

Tags: floats, captions, citing, rmarkdown

I'm struggling to put a citation inside a figure caption. I'm writing my document in rmarkdown using markdown citations i.e. `[@bibtexCitationkey]`, but using LaTeX for figures and tables. I'd like to be able to put citations within figure and table captions, but I've tried the following without success.

```
---
title: "Table tests"
csl: harvard-cite-them-right.csl  
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \graphicspath{ {./figs&tabs/} }

bibliography: library.bib
---

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{gr1_lrg.jpg}
\caption {Caption text [@Levin2013] or caption text \cite{Levin2013}}

\label{f:ckd}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

This produces:
Caption text @Levin2013 or caption text [?]

In the citations in markdown format are working in the rest of the document, there's no problem with my .bib

Comment: Did you try the second syntax without the `@`, so `\cite{Levin2013}`?

Comment: Thanks @Marijn. Just tried that, but same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

1. It seems that you want also HTML and Word outputs, but LaTeX code in Rmarkdowm only is useful for the PDF output, otherwise is omitted. Maybe not a good idea use it?
2. Rmarkdown inside LaTeX command or environment is parsed by LaTeX rules. So `[@Levin2013]` inside a `\caption{}` is not a cite, is just plain text.
3. Bibliography in Rmarkdown is processed by default by `pandoc-citeproc`, so even in the LaTeX version the bibliograhy is not a `\bibliography` command, nor `\printbibliography`  nor even a `thebibliography` with \bibitems, but just directly the references with `\hypertarget`, so `\cite`-like commands have nothing to do.
4. You can force the use of a true bibtex or biblatex bibliography, but even then, the above apply, and you cannot nest freely LaTeX in markdown, or markdown in LaTeX.
5. R chunks is another way to make figure and tables, but add another layer of complexity of how the file is exported, so you cannot use directly markdown nor LaTeX inside `fig.cap` for instance, although there are tricks to do that (see the example).
6. Cross-references are limited in basic `rmarkdown`, but `bookdown`  is a interesting extension of rmarkdown that avoild also the need of use  `\label{}`  and/or  `\ref{}` commands in figures, that will work only for  PDF outputs.
7. Not very often, but sometimes in complex documents,  recognition of LaTeX code inside Rmarkdown fail miserably. Then is regarded as plain text, causing fatal errors and headaches.

Considering this, there are several options, and one is raw LaTeX floats, but it should be the last option, and without markdown:

---

[image: mwe]

---

`MimimalWorkingExample.Rmd`

````
---
linkcolor: blue
bibliography: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/msc/biblio.bib
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: no
    citation_package: biblatex
biblio-style: authoryear
biblatexoptions: maxbibnames=9
---

(ref:rudolph) *nice* cite: [@Lam94].

I recommend the figure \@ref(fig:foo) method: 

```{r foo, fig.cap= 'Caption \\emph{with} *very* (ref:rudolph)', echo=F, fig.align = 'center', out.width='10%'}

 knitr::include_graphics("/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png")
```

You can use also the figure \@ref(fig:bah) method:

![Caption text [@Lam94](\#fig:bah)](example-image-b.png){width=10%}

But I do not recommend the figure \ref{baz} method:

\begin{figure}[h]\centering 
\includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption {Caption text \autocite{Lam94}.\label{baz}}
\end{figure}
````

Comment: thanks for this clear answer. I had been thinking of starting to use bookdown. I think you're right that I need to avoid using laTeX floats, though I have some large tables that I need packages such as `longtable` so I think I'll need to keep using LaTeX for tables. In your first example is it necessary to create the `(ref:rudolph)` outside the code chunk, or can I just include [@citationkey] inside the code chunk?

Comment: Also, @Fran, because I use LaTeX for some equations with `mathfont` I think I will be knitting to PDF for the the final piece of work as the formatting looks best, but my supervisor likes to be able to comment on drafts using microsoft word, hence I'm trying to be able to knit to both as much as possible.

Comment: @MarkDavies The  [@citationkey] included directly  will be regarded as plain text, as it is  the `*very*` word in the first caption of my example.  Another  alternative `\\cite{citationkey}` but then will work only for LaTeX. You can a caption inside the chunk, using some like  `fig.cap=mycap` and inside the R chunk  `mycap <- "My caption"`  but the problem is the same. If R make the caption, just read plain text.

Comment: @MarkDavies  rmarkdown table are exported to `longtable` by default, and you can aldo do that from R chunk with with kable or xtable, for instance.  I also include  LaTeX in Rmardown as far I needed, but if you want a Word version of this mix first export to  pure LateX and only then from LaTeX to any compatible format (odt,html, rtf).

Comment: too bad the recommended approach does not seem to work in case of Word doc output

Comment: @mspices No true. Output to `bookdown::word_document2: default` in the recommended first figure should be correct. If a remember correctly (I cannot test it now) it will not link  "1994" to the reference, because biblatex cannot be used for this output, but it should be fine at any other respect.  Be sure that you are using a correct YAML header and that .bib and .png  files are in the correct place (place them all to the working directory and remove all the directory paths in the MWE, to avoid mistakes in that sense).

Comment: @Fran thanks, I was using `word_document`